# Headset mic not working (or detected) in PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, microphone, headphones

I bought a headset with built-in mic today. It does its main job of listening to audio. However, the built-in does not work in PC. However, it does work in mobile and laptops.

The only difference that I can think of between mobile/laptop and PC is that the PC has separate audio output and input jacks. On the other hand, the mobile and laptops have just one.

I tried inserting the headphone pin in both the mic jack and the audio output jack. It only outputs audio in both of them and does not record anything.

How can I get it to work in PC?

Thanks.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PC needs separate mic and phones plugs. Your headset has a single plug with both mic and phones in one plug. You need an adapter to plug between PC and headset to make them compatible.

Comment: Thanks Justme. :) I just have one more question. Even if there are separate plugs, why does my headset play audio in both slots? Shouldn't it just record when inserted in the mic slot?

Comment: No, headset will only be compatible with the headphone jack and work as headphones in the headphones jack. It will not work as a microphone in the microphone jack, because the microphone jack would try to use the headphone pins as microphone.